# Detecting many-to-many relationship changes in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nsnotifications

We have a pretty robust and fleshed-out system for detecting changes on the models in our iOS app using `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.  This works well for our attribute changes as well as changes in 1:1 and 1:M relationships.

We're trying to build in some M:M relationships to our schema now and I'm struggling to see how Coredata's notification system will allow us to observe specific changes in M:M relationships.

I'm guessing that if a M:M relationship changed, the two objects involved in the change would both appear in the `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` list, but there wouldn't be any specific annotation to say that a M:M relationship between them had changed, or which M:M relationship that was (assuming there are possibly more than one M:M relationship between two models).

Has anyone had any luck in using Coredata's notifications system to detect changes in M:M relationships?  Or are they basically difficult to work with and people tend to resort to explicitly creating the "joining table" as a real type (and thereby ending up with two 1:M relationships instead of a single M:M relationship)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: when a M:M relationship changes, the objects at both ends of the relationship show up in the appropriate dictionaries in the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

If you're scanning the objects looking for the specific properties that have changed, you can use the method `changedValues` (or, better, `changedValuesForCurrentEvent` on ios5) to find out the property names. You are probably already doing this.

You can then inspect the model to see if any given property is many:many or not:

```
-(void)notifyObjectsChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
  assert([NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification isEqual:note.name]);
  for (NSManagedObject *mo in [note.userInfo objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey])
  {
    NSLog(@"for %@ :", mo.objectID);
    NSDictionary *rels = mo.entity.relationshipsByName;
    for (NSString *prop in [mo.changedValuesForCurrentEvent allKeys])
    {
      NSRelationshipDescription *rel = [rels objectForKey:prop];
      if (rel.isToMany && rel.inverseRelationship.isToMany)
        NSLog(@"many-to-many relationship %@ changed", prop);
    }
  }
}
```

(untested, off the top of my head, watch for typos!)

The essential technique is that managed objects keep references to the object model description, which you can inspect at runtime.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't aware of `changedValues` or `changedValuesForCurrentEvent`.  Thanks for this, they will do perfectly.